# I'm trying to make it so that the number cant be increased in a TextBox

Tags: c#

I'm a noobie who is trying to make it's so that the user can't increase the number in a textbox from a .mdf file, but when I test run and test this part of the program it crashes and I see a "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'" error message.

```
private void HoeveelheidTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (42 < int.Parse(hoeveelheidTextBox.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("je kan niet schoenen erbij doen");
                {
                    hoeveelheidTextBox.ToString();
                    hoeveelheidTextBox.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
```

(je kan niet schoenen erbij doen = you can't add anymore shoe's
hoeveelheid = amount)

As you can see in the code I tried converting the TextBox back into a string, However, I still get the error.

My desired outcome is that the program clears the TextBox when the number is larger then what it first was.

Comment: That means the value in the `hoeveelheidTextBox.Text` is not convertable to an integer

Comment: A note: Not sure what are up to here, though the `int.Parse` doesn't make the `hoeveelheidTextBox.Text` a number, so not useful to do `hoeveelheidTextBox.ToString()`

Comment: Take a look at the `TryParse` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that there's a possibility that `HoeveelheidTextBox` has a value which is **not** a valid `int` value (say, an *empty string*); let's use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`:

```
  private void HoeveelheidTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (int.TryParse(hoeveelheidTextBox.Text, out int value)) {
      // TryParse succeeded; hoeveelheidTextBox.Text has an integer value
      // Let's check what the value is
      if (42 < value) {
        // hoeveelheidTextBox.Text has an integer value that exceeds 42
        MessageBox.Show("je kan niet schoenen erbij doen");

        hoeveelheidTextBox.Text = "";
      }
      else {
        // hoeveelheidTextBox.Text has an integer value which is 42 or below it
      }
    }
    else { // TryParse failed; 
      // hoeveelheidTextBox.Text doesn't have an integer value 
      // (it can be an empty string, "bla-bla-bla" etc.)
      hoeveelheidTextBox.Text = ""; 
    } 
  }
```